# XPST0017 Xpath syntax error

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm trying to run a script to pull a combination of the last 2 0's from an xml field and replace them with a random number between 10 and 60.

however the following error appeared

XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 15 on line 31 in {randomnr:rand()}:

Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {uri:nonexistant}rand()

what am I doing wrong? I know that everything besides the javascript call works

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:randomnr="uri:nonexistant"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:saxon="uri:http://saxon.sf.net/">
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
          <saxon:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="randomnr">
            <![CDATA[
            function rand()
            {
                 return"" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 60) + 10);
             }
            ]]>
        </saxon:script>
      <xsl:variable name="basename">
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
      <xsl:with-param name="string1" select="$filename" />
      <xsl:with-param name="string2" select="'00'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:value-of select="$basename" />
     <xsl:value-of select="randomnr:rand()"/>
```

Comment: I am not aware of a `saxon:script` element, and the Saxon extension namespace is different anyway from the one you used. I don't think Saxon 9 has any support for calling into Javascript at all. If you want a random number you can call into Java if supported or use the XPath 3.1 feature for that if supported.

Comment: See http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/ for the defined extension elements, there is no `saxon:script` element.

Comment: apparently I was looking at an older version of the saxon documentation 
then which had a top-level elements saxon:script.

Comment: There is http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/exslt-random/random-sequence.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/random-number-generator.html support in the commercial versions of Saxon 9.7.

Comment: declaring xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" and
 <xsl:value-of select="fn:random-number-generator()?permute(10 to 60)"/> just returns unknown system function

Comment: Consider to tell us exactly which Saxon version you use, otherwise it is rather pointless trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions concerning Saxon.

Take a look at http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/extensions.html#saxon:script

It reads: *The language attribute is mandatory, and must take the value "java"*.
Otherwise Saxon ignores the `saxon:script` element.

I can suggest another solution, based on invoking Java methods:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:math="java.lang.Math">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="math:floor((math:random() * 60) + 10)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried it on http://xsltransform.net/ and found that it works in *Xalan* and *Saxon 6.5.5* modes.
Unfortunately, in *Saxon HE* and *Saxon EE* modes it fails.

Note that *math* namespace points to fully qualified Java class name.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing wrong? You are consulting some very ancient documentation (and probably extrapolating from what it actually says). There may have been a time when saxon:script existed, but (a) it was a very long time ago, and (b) it never supported calling Javascript.